# COM dll unregister issue

Tags: c++, windows, com, atl, dcom

I have a project which has many COM dlls, for a requirement I had to unregister a COM Dll, which I did by calling `Regsvr32 -u` option and the dll is unregistered.

This de-register operation seems to remove an interface say `ICommon` interface, which is making other COM objects unusable.

This `ICommon` interface is implemented by all other COM Components, in the registry script of the unregistered COM Dll, I don't see any code that removes this `ICommon` interface form registry, how is this getting removed.

How is the interface information removed for a given `CoClass`, does the BEGIN_COM_MAP and `COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY` play any role?

Comment: When you view the type library, is the `ICommon` interface visible in all the COM component dlls that use `ICommon`?

Comment: You might have this interface on 2+ type libraries (typical issue) and then unreg'ging of ANY removes interface registration.

Comment: If this is the issue, a quick fix might be to re-register any of remaining libraries with this interface. A proper fix would be to eliminate duplications on the type libraries.

Comment: Thanks Roman...i will if this is feasible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

COM is rife with DLL Hell problems.  The failure mode here is that uninstalling the server will also remove the keys from HKLM\Software\Classes\Interface.  Which tells COM which proxy/stub implementation should be used to marshal the interface across apartment boundaries.  The ProxyStubClsId32 key for the interface identifies the proxy.

So that breaks any client program that use other COM servers that implement the interface, they can no longer marshal the interface and they will die at runtime with E_NOINTERFACE.  In itself a confuzzling error code, you'd assume that the interface somehow has vanished but it actually complains about the COM object not implementing IMarshal.  The last gasp when COM cannot find the key in the registry.

Not that this is normally hard to fix, you'd simply have to re-register the COM server that fails, it will put the key back.

There is no real defense against this lossage, you'd have to implement an elaborate reference counting scheme that records how many COM servers have a dependency on the the proxy and only remove the key (and the DLL, if it is a custom proxy) when it counts down to zero.  This has been done, it however takes just a single installer that doesn't buy into the scheme, or an unwise Regsvr32.exe /u executed from the command line like you did, to make it fail.

Comment: This is all true, of course, but the defense is pretty simple - to never have an interface on 2+ type libraries. Then there is no situation that one thing is gone and another thing is still using the gone thing. IDL `importlib` is the tool to reference type libraries one another.

Comment: +1 I was about to write up this nearly verbatim. I *never* merge proxy-stub info for interfaces that are shared among multiple PEs for this very reason, opting for a separate type lib and if-needed a stand-alone marshaller (which I try to avoid as well).

Comment: This is exactly the error i see...thanks for taking time out to answer this question

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these elements do play a role, so does the typelib, used by `regsvr32`.

If the `ICommon` interface is visible, seen by viewing the typelib of the COM component, the that type is seen as being "owned" by the component and the `regsvr32` process adds that component as the location of that interface. On removal, the opposite it applied. So whilst the `ICommon` interface is still used, since a component that is seen as the "owner" of the interface is removed, the registration of the interface is also removed. A new "owner" is not automatically installed (or registered), this must be done by registering a suitable component again.

I recommend to isolate the `ICommon` interface to a single typelib (COM component) and import that typelib wherever the interface is required, thereby ensuring a single "owner" of the interface.

*Note:* based on experience with some inherited code (with this issue) I have had to fix, be very careful when importing or trying to re-declare system interfaces (e.g. `ISerializable` etc.) since `regsvr32` could remove those from the registry as well; causing a world of pain. The uninstall in this case almost wrecked the entire system.